# How to get the item position in a ListView and GridView outside the adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-gridview

I'm trying to get a View position through his view hierarchy.

When I have a RecyclerView, for get the current view position I do:

```
if(view.getParent() instanceof RecyclerView){ 
  RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)view.getParent();
  if(rv.getLayoutManager()!=null) {
     position = rv.getLayoutManager().getPosition(view);
  }
}
```

But when a **ListView or GridView** appears, I'm not able to get a Layout Manager to get the position of the view. The idea is to make it in a generic way, **without knowing the Custom Adapter the view has**.

I have tried to get the position through the ListView and GridView adapter but I dont see any method that do that.

Someone can help me?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Create interface for get position for outside adapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
if(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
   position = ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).indexOfChild(view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create interface for get position for outside adapter class

here is adapter code:

```
public class ReportMediaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<File> reportMediaList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    private int selectedPos = -1;
    private OnRemoveImage onRemoveImage;

    public ReportMediaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<File> reportMediaList, OnRemoveImage onRemoveImage) {
        this.reportMediaList = reportMediaList;
        this.onRemoveImage = onRemoveImage;
        this.context = context;
    }

    **public interface OnRemoveImage {
        void onRemove(int pos);
    }**

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView iv_image, iv_remove;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iv_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
            iv_remove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_remove);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return reportMediaList.size()-1;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_media, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            MyViewHolder menuItemHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            CommonMethods.loadImage(context, reportMediaList.get(position), menuItemHolder.iv_image);
            menuItemHolder.iv_remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    **onRemoveImage.onRemove(position);**
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is activity code:

```
@Override
    public void onRemove(int pos) {

        // use adapter position

    }
```